# How to fetch the url of all the browsers which are running on windows

Tags: python, url, browser, tabs

```
From pywinauto import Application
app=Application (backend ="uia")
app. Connect (title_re=".*Chrome.*")
element_name="Address and search bar"
dlg =app.top_window()
Url=dlg.child_windows(title =element _name, control _type ="edit").get _value
```

to fetch the url of allthe browsers on active window

Comment: Do you want all the urls from an already opened browser window?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To fetch the url of current tab of firefox ,edge safari browsers